# How to get "top &" command to work in my own shell in C?

Tags: c, bash, shell, fork, child-process

I have gotten & working so if I do

> ls -l &

then it will continue asking for input running both child and parent concurrently. However doing

> top &

outputs the entire processes log from top (preventing user from seeing next prompt) which is not how a normal shell works. In a normal shell the top & command suspends the top to the background while allowing one to still input the next command.

here is my relevant code for execvp(), fork() and wait().

```
pid = fork();     

if(pid < 0){            
    return 1;
}
else if (pid == 0){
    execvp(args[0], args);              
}       
else{
     /* if no ampersand, wait for child to finish */
    if(!ampersand){
        while(wait(&status) != pid);
    }
                                    
}
```

any tips or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to learn how job control is implemented.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Implementing-a-Shell.html